# Wordpress with NGINX as reverse proxy and Apache2 as php webserver keep redirecting to localhost instead of using the domain

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, nginx

I have just installed wordpress in a subdirectory of my domain: exaple.com/wordpress/

When I enter the url:

```
 http://exaple.com/wordpress/
```

I am redirected to :

```
  https://localhost/wordpress/
```

Apache2 is listening on port 8080
NGINX is listening on port 80, 443

I use NGINX as a reverse proxy, the configuration is the following:

```
    server {
        server_name example.com;
        location / {
                proxy_pass       http://localhost:8080;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
 }
 server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

        server_name example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
 }
```

Apache configuration is:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/example.com"
    ServerName example.com

    <Directory "/var/www/example.com">
        Options MultiViews FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    TransferLog /var/log/apache2/nextcloud_access.log
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/nextcloud_error.log


</VirtualHost>
```

In the WordPress database, table wp_options, I have already changed the two rows "siteurl" and "home" from:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/
```

to:

```
http://example.com/wordpress/
```

It is still not working.

Comment: The important thing here is: `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;` just below the `proxy_pass`, otherwise, "upstream" will get the host name of the given URL (http://localhost...)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was on this post:

[Problems with Nginx Reverse SSL Proxy for Apache for WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66263361/problems-with-nginx-reverse-ssl-proxy-for-apache-for-wordpress?rq=2)

To make that work I changed Nginx configuration like this:

```
    server {
        server_name example.com;
        location / {
                proxy_pass       http://localhost:8080;

proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;


        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
 }
 server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

        server_name example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
 }
```

Within the WordPress installation I changed the configuration while wp-config.php adding the following code immediately after the first line "<?PHP" (at the end of the file it does not work):

```
/**If we got HTTPS from Nginx, we must reply the same way */
if ( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https' )
{
        $_SERVER['HTTPS']       = 'on';
    $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = '443';
        define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
}

/**When replying make sure the reply HOST is set to Nginx Rerverse Proxy address, not us */
if ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']) )
{
        $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'];
}
```